# Trying to setup spring boot cloud config server with ssh private key file and getting: ucom.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: USERAUTH fail

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I am trying to setup spring boot cloud config server with ssh private key file and getting: ucom.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: USERAUTH fail
My application.properties file:

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=git@bitbucket.org:test/test.git
spring.cloud.config.server.git.clone-on-start=true
spring.security.user.name=root
spring.security.user.password=s3cr3t

spring.cloud.config.server.git.ignore-local-ssh-settings: true
spring.cloud.config.server.git.private-key:
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I'm getting `ucom.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: USERAUTH fail`.

I have suspicion that it is due to incorrectly placed key.
How to put ssh key to spring boot application.properties file?

Comment: I would try to put `=` instead of `:` as a delimeter for properties and use \ at the end of each line.

Comment: Just like the above answer. This works!! spring.cloud.config.server.git.private-key=-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n\
MIIEpAIBAAKCAQEAszmCR06LVHk/kNYV6LoYgEfHlK4rp75sCsRJ7rdAbWNED+yB\
....
EeBgS282jUBkXZ6WpzqHCcku3Avs3ajzsC1WaEYx0tCiBxSkiJlaLQ==\n\
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

Answer (score 0):

I have just tested the reading of this property and I think that the beggining and ending of PEM key should be placed in new lines. You can try setting the property like this :

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.private-key=-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n\
MIIEpAIBAAKCAQEAszmCR06LVHk/kNYV6LoYgEfHlK4rp75sCsRJ7rdAbWNED+yB\
bneOm5gue0LGIhT7iTP9D7aN6bKVHv1SBconCA7Pa2NMA9epcMT5ecJc8ndpZOFn\
iqM77jmMMPvj8EIC06w5oK5zoYwpGotYQFHllf8M+20HtW2fZdPYAYwLcVdmc5tI\
vLoS+10qw5D3X9zrwk2Cbt37Iqnz1cHOQq+g7sxgVgt18aIKKeg0JslaGqSlWMoT\
ICUMHj89E4BMHj8ND8otSXHL+VhN+ghd7w1MpckxLWBsNs1+G1FuiJEVAtRq/j+8\
SOilxgifvI1LqpZ5kO01XFlmkcuN4NMT03qpcwIDAQABAoIBAB5oQGk2sz7mv1kk\
aV0tzaBeDUd1cWSpUw1UljKRFrY4ZEDLYH5MfH57iE9TWehIZRC3KFU1JMikitZS\
JktjK9IbKSfQFgKE4XOHh8gXqMteZRw/feCwpydYzic1ZUvK903QZ4qSbn3XGNYv\
FA79lhUny50Qt4EZkzSkh35js0FMSR9VmyXENxN6IgXUZyoaNAATr44Vkd488BY2\
7PvdOniemo8/8p4Ij0Aq9Q7rOtm77ZXjyFRX5mDTi2ndSllMEhVcWXHSii+ukbvF\
117Ns+8M7VWroNfRzI+Ilm/Xz/ePOLlNoYcY0h5+QM9vMPTX9Cpl5WofgOMK1sKd\
mSdI4ukCgYEA12kcu0aDyIrEPHcyaT9izSFply0Uon2QKS9EQn6cr83vaEGViamh\
f5q1coYouGnsLfbgKolEMKsYtbmJvInPFDCdc2x0Fmc207Wp1OECsN+HwElEXkrs\
uPDpGQgs5odjN5Grue9837920oG3UBBdVDAKly2dTOcvoWW+88seFSUCgYEA1P7f\
p78HDMQ8zTy5+3Rd4+lmJjPsY618XxSQ80j8Elrhi/DyTMA0XGc5c3cKRPmSj+JD\
GN34WQbw7JO2mKM7YJs+tkSBeTKce8F3cZQy1jy3LNHCtfXylOxmxOFKynV5h2b/\
jno+pGdmAPK5yvnGASd2eujtzt+AL07XiD2LnLcCgYEAsFRz131WfP/SuShdlLf1\
WbODKuQVIxojuwLdHo1kF6k805v0G/dGoxzycOgPRz41vj57q3Yn4qr8FC3n6PTq\
FT3idUyPDpO41r67Ye469KxWBHo1Q/aTJqTWOs5tatvixOcyqoa3MrUZQCI8+4YZ\
z8Nvt+b3/66zV6vhDtHzMx0CgYAvWW2M0+mUS/ecRHivzqGkrdkYewh87C8uz9qd\
SsdGqU9kla63oy7Ar+3Unkz5ImYTeGAkIgw4dlOOtBOugPMNOdXKHRaPQ9IHrO2J\
oUFf4OVzoDnhy4ge1SLPd6nxsgXPNPVwzfopABdr9Ima9sWusgAjuK5NA+ByI9vE\
HLJxpwKBgQCTM938cdx457ag1hS6EaEKyqljS1/B8ozptB4cy3h0hzw0crNmW84/\
1Lt9MJmeR4FrWitQkkVLZL3SrYzrP2i+uDd4wVVD5epvnGP/Bk6g05/eB9LgDRx/\
EeBgS282jUBkXZ6WpzqHCcku3Avs3ajzsC1WaEYx0tCiBxSkiJlaLQ==\n\
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Notice the line breaks in the beggining and ending.