# USERAUTH fail with private key file for Github and Spring cloud config

Tags: spring-boot, github, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I tried to use the method for using private key (that has passphrase and is added to ssh-agent from file) (according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54798651) stack post):

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: git@github.com-forApp:myorg/myrepo.git
          search-paths: '{application}'
          clone-on-start: true
          private_key_file: ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

but I keep getting

> org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException:
>   git@github.com:myorg/myrepo.git: USERAUTH fail

Do I have to do it exactly as [doc says](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html#_git_ssh_configuration_using_properties) with pasting the key into config file or can one just point to the key file somehow?

**EDIT**

Actually it turns out that the `private_key_file` is not needed at all or ignored by Spring. But you need the `~/.ssh/config` section pointing to private key to use:

```
Host github.com-forApp # used in spring uri 
       HostName github.com
       User git
       IdentityFile ~/.ssh/gitHubKey
```

Comment: Did you configure your github to accept your ssh key ?

Comment: @BurakAkyıldız yes, eg  when I use git it uses my ssh key no login/pass needed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to replicate your behavior and resolved it with following. Let me know your thoughts.

`USERAUTH fail` is happening because you are not providing the passphrase for the RSA private key.(`password` for Basic Auth and `passphrase` for ssh private key)

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: git@github.com:myorg/myrepo.git
          search-paths: '{application}'
          clone-on-start: true
          passphrase: myprivatekeypassword
```

By default `~/.ssh/id_rsa` is sent during GIT SSH Authentication(Test with command `ssh -vT git@github.com`. You don't need to specify it in configuration. Also, I am not sure whether `private_key_file` works or not, since I don't see any official documentation for it.

If you have different named RSA file under `.ssh` then I would advise to create config file under `~/.ssh/config` with github host details and identify file.

Here is one example.

```
Host github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mygitid_rsa
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51407594/5030709) stack answer for more details which desired the configuration providing private key file path within config.

Comment: It was all about adding `passphrase` not it works even with `private_key_file` which is also present in the answer you linked. It works regardless if it is added to `ssh-agent` or not. Only while addng changes to config repo it asks for the passphrase

Comment: @mCs correct. adding it to ssh-agent doesn't matter since JGit library underlying is not referring it.

Comment: Actually it turns out that the `private_key_file` is not needed at all or ignored by Spring. But you need the `~/.ssh/config` section pointing to private key to use as in my question

Comment: @mCs yes. the stack answer I shared as well was desiring the feature but it's not supported yet!.